# Serialize string to standard URL-encoded notation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need serialize a string to a standard URL-encoded notation
my string has some blank spaces and parentheses:

```
string = "( 3.141516, 3.1415), 3,1415";
```

and I need get it at serverside as a only value - var, how can I do that in order to sent it as a query string???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without any jQuery at all: [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

With jQuery, assuming you're using something like [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/):

```
$.get('http://example.com/', {foo: '( 3.141516, 3.1415), 3,1415'}, callback);
```

and jQuery will automagically do the URL-encoding for you.

Comment: ,@Matt Ball you know a proper way to use it with $.getscript()?

Comment: You have to use `encodeURIComponent()` since there is no `data` argument overload for `$.getScript()`. Just read the API docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: yeah, I got it..Thanks @Matt Ball